# Fiware: Cepheus security considerations?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How can we add security between Orion broker and Cepheus?

How can we use Cepheus with a protected Orion broker (pep is used to secure the access to the broker)?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiware-Cepheus](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus) currently does not act as an OAuth client and does not make requests to an IDM server to retrieve the OAuth token by itself.

However Fiware-Cepheus handles the three HTTP headers required by Orion Policy Enforcement Point (PEP) proxies : `x-auth-token`, `fiware-servicepath` and `fiware-service`.

Theses headers values can be set for either Cepheus Broker or Cepheus CEP from configuration settings.

For Cepheus Broker, this configuration is currently static. See [Configuration section of the Admin manual](http://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/broker/index.html#configuration).

```
remote.serviceName=tenant
remote.servicePath=test/example
remote.authToken=OAUTH_TOKEN
```

For Cepheus CEP, this configuration is more dynamic as it is part of the CEP rules provisioning and can be done independently for each outgoing event. See [Configuration section of the User manual](http://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cep/configuration/index.html).

```json
"out": [
  {
    "id": "FloorX",
    "type": "Floor",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "temperature",
        "type": "double",
        "metadata": [
          {
            "name": "unit",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "brokers": [
      {
        "url": "http://orion.fiware.org:3000",
        "serviceName": "tenant",
        "servicePath": "test/example",
        "authToken": "OAUTH_TOKEN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```